# Is there a way to remove anonymous Runnables from a Handler?

Tags: java, android

```
Handler h = new Handler();
h.postDelayed(new Runnable(){...}, 5000);
```

Is there any way to clear this prior to the 5 second expiration or does the Handler not have a public method that I can use to null out the anonymous `Runnable`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any way to clear this prior to the 5 second expiration

I think this should make a trick (but Runnable needs to be not anonymous):

```
handler.removeCallBacks(runnable);
```

For anonymous runnables should work:

```
handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);
```

What [source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacksAndMessages%28java.lang.Object%29) says:

> Remove any pending posts of callbacks and sent messages whose obj is
>   token. If token is null, all callbacks and messages will be removed.

Comment: @Dr.Dredel check the docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html#removeCallbacks(java.lang.Runnable)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel so how is actual state? I hope it works as you wanted.